# Why does my code break when I take out Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The existing code renders. However, when I remove `Router` from line 2 as an import, even though it's not being used, it breaks.

*Correction: The page still renders when I remove Router. However, it just displays a blank page. When I inspect it, I no longer get anything in the **div id="root"** tags.*

When I compile, of course I get "Line 2:27:  'Router' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars"

Why is this? Or does anyone have any insight?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import PlanTripPage from './PlanTripPage';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import ItineraryPage from './ItineraryPage';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/plan-trip" element={<PlanTripPage />} />
        <Route path="/itinerary" element={<ItineraryPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my index file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I see no reason for removing the unused `BrowserRouter as Router` import to break anything. When you "compile" it what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this Drew. Actually I misspoke, it still renders when I remove Router. However, it's just a blank page now. It goes from displaying the page, to just a blank white page. When I inspect it, I no longer get anything in the body or <div id="root">.

Comment: What's the versions (of react and react-router-dom)?

Comment: @raina77ow        

"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are doing the deletion wrong.

This code should work correctly without errors:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import PlanTripPage from './PlanTripPage';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import ItineraryPage from './ItineraryPage';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/plan-trip" element={<PlanTripPage />} />
        <Route path="/itinerary" element={<ItineraryPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Or if the problem persists, check other components.

Comment: Can I add an emoji here for "I'm dumb?"

This worked. Thank you! Rather than just deleting Router...Had to remove "BrowserRouter as" also

Comment: It is not so. Everyone can make mistakes sometimes. Good that it worked.